# Using contains taking time to load performance issue

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

List of values getting for sample 8000 and above records

```
   // Below taking list of values

   List<Alldetails>details =_context.Tax.ToList();
```

//specific getting array of id am using

```
 int[]person =details.groupby(d=>d.taxId).select(s=>s.key).Toarray();
```

// Below conditions there person of contains ex:1000 id while using contains performance is too slow can anyone suggest me to reduce the time of loading

```
     IQueryable<int> transLocationIds = _context.company
                   .Where(c =>person.Contains(c.alltaxId)&& c.deleteFlag ==1)
                   .Select(d=>d.rollId);
```

In the scenario the array of person values its using contains lacks of time to load ...

Comment: what is "lacks of time to load"?

Comment: while getting array of person id values its elapsed time is good,when the next condition of  IQueryable<int>..  person.contains(c.alltaxId) elapsed time takes miilisecond to second of 950 records

Comment: Its person of array values checking below condition taking slow of performance

Comment: There's no need to create an `int[]person` array and then uses it as a filter like `person.contains(id)`. Create a `IQueryable<int>`  instead. Something like `var person = _context.Tax.GroupBy(d=>d.taxId).Select(s=>s.Key);`  & then `IList<int> transLocationIds = _context.Company.Where(c =>person.Contains(c.allTaxId)&& c.deleteFlag ==1).Select(d=>d.rollId).ToList();` . This will generate a single one sql `SELECT [c].[rollId] FROM [Company] AS [c] WHERE [c].[allTaxId] IN ( SELECT [d].[taxId] AS [Key] FROM [Tax] AS [d] GROUP BY [d].[taxId]) AND ([c].[deleteFlag] = 1)`

Comment: Also, make sure the related columns (especially the taxId, alltaxId) are indexed.

Comment: ya itminus thanks... before its get 6.75 seconds now its reduce of 1.95 seconds but  in our project based on standard we avoid using var so i used List<int>person

Comment: @GauthamSrinivasan Glad to hear it helps . As a side note, the `var` won't affect the performance as it's just a syntax sugar :) . Also, the way you get `List<int> person` seems not efficient, might be selecting distinct is better? Also, Try use something like `Where(x => Tax.Any(t => t.taxId == x.id))` ,  I guess in this way it will be translated to `exists` instead of `in`. I think using `Exists` is faster than `IN`.